# touch events event delegation with jquery's .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, event-delegation

So I have this javascript code that listens for touch events on all elements in the document.

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
```

That works fine except I only want to **listen for those events on items of the class of dataCard (`.dataCard`) and all of their children that are not anchors `<a>`.**

So how I thought to fix that would be through creating a jQuery selector, as I am using jQuery earlier in the page, and calling the `.addEventListener()` on that. That didn't work.

This is what I tried:

```
$('.dataCard, .dataCard *:not(a)').addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
$('.dataCard, .dataCard *:not(a)').addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
$('.dataCard, .dataCard *:not(a)').addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
$('.dataCard, .dataCard *:not(a)').addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
```

As I mentioned before that didn't work. I guess because jQuery and JS don't mix well at times.

Now, I realised that I also need to delegate the events to all instances of `.dataCard` ( those that exist now or those that may be programmatically created ).

This is a good thing because I could now use an entire jQuery solution with `.on()` function.

This is what I tried:

```
$('#main').on('touchstart', '.dataCard', function(event){
    touchHandler(event);
});
$('#main').on('touchmove', '.dataCard', function(event){
touchHandler(event);
});
$('#main').on('touchend', '.dataCard', function(event){
touchHandler(event);
});
$('#main').on('touchcancel', '.dataCard', function(event){
touchHandler(event);
});
```

Now, `#main` is stable and will always exist and it is the `.dataCard`s that some exist and some will be programmatically added.

So in terms of event-delegation, this works fine. My problem is that now this is not working either.

I think because the `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`, and `touchcancel` are not jQuery events that on can recognise.

So my question is, **How can I do what my first block of code does (add event listeners for those touch events) only for all instances of `.dataCard`, those that exist and are programmatically created, in jQuery or plain / vanilla js?**

Comment: By the way, you have some unnecessary function wrapping in the `.on` calls. You don't need that anonymous function; just do `.on('event', '.elem', touchHandler);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event `target` property and test if that is an instance of `.dataCard`:

```
$('#main').on('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', '.dataCard', function(event){
    if($(event.target).is('.dataCard')) {
        touchHandler(event);
    }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXqXr/1) I added a click handler as well, so you can test it in a desktop browser.

As an aside, you can register multiple event listeners with the same handler by providing a space-delimited list as the first parameter of `on()`.

Comment: So, this is a shorthand what I was trying to do. But it is not working.

I'm trying to get objects draggable with jQuery UI's `.draggable()` to be draggable on multi-touch in android and iOS. This script does that, it makes it draggable on desktop and multi-touch: https://gist.github.com/theirf/6176263, but it also prevents anything in the object being dragged from being clicked. So I wanted to bind those touch events to only `.dataCard` and not its children so that its children could be clicked or tapped on mobile.

Comment: How is it not working? It seems to work in the demo I posted.

Comment: Demo works fine, but when I apply it, it doesn't work. I provided some background info in my comment ( I edited it ).

Comment: Is your touchhandler returning `false` or calling `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: This is what all my code to make `.dataCard` draggable on desktop and multi-touch looks like including your suggestions. https://gist.github.com/theirf/6176222. Here is a link to a URL where it is: http://goo.gl/aOTLla. The .dataCards are each of those white rectangles.

Comment: No I don't think so. I posted all my code in the comment before this one and a live URL.

Comment: Sorry if I am being impatient, but have you figured out how to make `.dataCard`s draggable on mobile and have their children clickable? I am trying everything I can find and nothing is working :-/

Comment: I'm not seeing any issue... I think it might be helpful for you to post this as a new question with more of the details about what your trying to accomplish with the draggable widgets and what's not working. An example would be helpful too

Comment: i posted a new question if you want to take a look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18111477/2450243

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sending array parameters to `.on()` and with appropriate selectors.

```
$(function() {
    $('.dataCard *:not(a)', '#main').on({
        touchstart: function() {
           console.log('touchstart');
        },
        touchmove: function() {
          console.log('touchmove');
        },
        touchend: function() {
          console.log('touchend');
        },
        touchcancel: function() {
          console.log('touchcancel');
        }
    });
});
```

Here  is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Fac/).